# how do I pass a textfile through a parameter in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

trying to pass a text file into a function to do some stuff in Scala, but I don't know how to pass it into the function.

I want to pass it in as I have multiple text files and the work done is quite intense

```
object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val books = sc.textFile(
      "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/books/books2/*"
    )
checkLang(books)

}


def checkLang (books: textFile)  = {


//do sonething

}
```

Comment: `books` is not a `textFile` is a **RDD[String]** - please read the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#textFile(path:String,minPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

def checkLang (books: RDD[String]){
//do stuff

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.